# How to change the displayed value when the view is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have this notification list which I have created using HTML and Thymeleaf. Here I am displaying the number of notifications using `${#lists.size(notifications)}` which displays the value properly.

```
<li class="dropdown messages-menu">
  <a id="notification-href" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    <span class="label label-success"><span id ="notification-count" th:text="${#lists.size(notifications)}"></span></span>
  </a>
  ...........
```

Once I have clicked the notification list, I want to change the notification count to zero. For this I have wrote following function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#notification-href").click(function(){
    $("#notification-count") == 0;
  });
});
```

This function does not work and I see no errors or exceptions either. Can anyone tell what is wrong here?

Comment: `.text('0')` or `.html('0')` instead of `==0`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
$("#notification-count").text('0')

// or

$("#notification-count").html('0');
```